# Error when inserting timestamp data from CSV into a Redshift table column which is of timestamp data type

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert data from an UTF-8 encoded CSV file into Redshift database but I get the error when attempting to insert timestamp into a column which has `timestamp` data type.

Here's a sample CSV:

```
employeeId,employeeDept,employeeName,shiftStartTime,shiftEndTime,onPremises
KL214691,John Smith,operations,2023-01-17 09:01:34,2023-01-17 16:52:41,1
KL214692,Samantha Kennedy,operations,2023-01-17 08:31:54,2023-01-17 16:09:10,1
```

Here's a sample table DDL:

```sql
create table historical_metrics_agent_status_time_on_status
(
    employeeid       varchar(10),
    employeename     varchar(100),
    employeedept     varchar(50),
    shiftstarttime   timestamp encode az64,
    shiftendtime     timestamp encode az64,
    onpremises       boolean,
    importdatetime   timestamp encode az64
)
    sortkey (employeeid);
```

The error message shows that there's an invalid digit `-` on position 4 in column `shiftstarttime` which has raw field value `2023-01-17 09:01:34`. It looks like it's not reading timestamp from CSV file properly. Is there something I'm missing in CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Check stl_load_errors for the exact row that is failing.  My guess is that one of the VARCHAR columns has a comma (,) in it and is throwing off the alignment of the CSV to table columns.  Like if one of the names is entered as “Smith, Joe”.

Comment: Well, stl_load_errors actually says err reason is `Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 4, Type: Long` for colname `shiftstarttime` of `timestamp` type. It seems like it's having problem with timestamp format (`2023-01-17 09:01:34`), although, as far as I know, it's valid format for Redshift data type.

Comment: It should give the entire line from the CSV as well.  To check that other data lines up.  It could also be that that character is not “-“ but a long dash character which some tools like to change dashes to.